# Eclipse Luna GC Overhead & Java Heap space

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-luna

Yesterday I installed Eclipse Luna to develop for android... I installed the google SDK and everything seemed to work fine... but when im looking a Graphical Layout of a given activity Luna blows up and starts to give me a screen as SS below:
[image: error screenshot]

To get around that i have to force quit eclipse and reopen... the problem is that XML is not a very good tool to build interfaces with... is there anything i can do to maybe increase the heap size?!? or something like that???

Extra Details:

- Running on MAC OS X latest version
- When the error happens im not under any kind of memory pressure situation... i have a 16gb set...
- So far my project has only 1 activity, so i dont know if this is happening with another screen
- This is my first android App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase the max heap size allocated to Eclipse by adjusting the `-Xmx` value in the `eclipse.ini` config file.

Example:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

See [this link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example) for the location of the file.

If the error is still occurring even after increasing the max heap size beyond the maximum allowable by the OS, then most probably your Eclipse installation has a bug in one of its plugins.

Comment: is there a "Go Wild" mode?!? like "shut-up and take my memory"?

Comment: No you can keep increasing the maximum heap until Eclipse is not even able to start.